# Poisson why does the parameter rate have to be positive?

Tags: probability

For a poisson distribution the parameter $\lambda$, the PMF is 
$$
P(k) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}, k = 0, 1,2...
$$
Why does the parameter $\lambda$ have to be positive ($\lambda > 0$)?

Answer (score 3):

If $\lambda=0$ then $X$ is almost surely $0$ which is not really Poisson.

If $\lambda$ is negative then $P(X=0)=e^{-\lambda}>1$ and $P(X=1)=\lambda e^{-\lambda}<0$ which are not probabilities

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $e^{-\lambda}=P(0)<1$.

This requires that $\lambda>0$.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter $\lambda$ is the average number of times an event occurs randomly in a given interval of time or space, so cannot be negative.